# Ico smart contract update

Tags: smart-contract, ico

I would like to update this code, because it is CDT 1.2.
I would like to update for CDT 1.5 or CDT 1.6.
What do I need to change?

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/currency.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

class hello : public eosio::contract {
  public:
      using contract::contract;

      hello(account_name self) : contract(self) {}

      /// @abi table 
      struct account {
          account_name owner;
          uint64_t balance;

          uint64_t primary_key() const { return owner; };
      };

      typedef eosio::multi_index<N(account), account> accs; 

      /// @abi action 
      void addbalance(account_name owner, uint64_t amount) {
           accs accounts(_self, owner);
           auto existing = accounts.find(owner);

           if (existing == accounts.end())
           {
               /* Add new account */
               accounts.emplace(_self, [&](auto& a) {
                   a.owner = owner;
                   a.balance = amount;
               });
           } else {
               /* Update existing account */
               const auto& st = *existing;
               accounts.modify(st, 0, [&](auto& a) {
                   a.balance += amount;
               });
           }
      }

      void on(const currency::transfer& t) {
          if (t.to == _self) {
              addbalance(t.from, t.quantity.amount);
          }
      }

      void use(account_name contract, account_name act) {
          if (act == N(transfer)) {
              on(unpack_action_data<currency::transfer>());
              return;
          }

          auto& thiscontract = *this;
          switch( act ) {
             EOSIO_API( hello, (addbalance));
          };
      }
};

extern "C" {
   [[noreturn]] void apply( uint64_t receiver, uint64_t code, uint64_t action ) {
      hello  h( receiver );
      h.use( code, action );
      eosio_exit(0);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this official page to guide you on how to install the latest CDT

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/installing-the-contract-development-toolkit

Comment: Thnak you. I saw, but I would like update beacuse I would like to us the CDT 1.6.

Comment: Once you have done the step I gave you in the link, your compiler will try to compile to the 1.6.1 cdt, if it dont compile maybe you gonna have to change part of your code

Comment: ok I tried, but fatal error: 'eosiolib/currency.hpp' file not found..which file neeod too change in cdt 1.6?

Comment: and affet a lot error, so I think I need change full code, or rewrite.

Comment: Yes, you gonna have to rewrite part of your code, we can help you for general stuff about EOS but we dont know how your program work

Answer (score 0):

This is a list of all changes to `eosio.cdt` at each version: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/releases

Start reading it from the version you are currently using until the version you want to migrate to. There was a large amount of breaking changes when going from v1.2.x to v1.3.x.

A lot of the libraries changes location and/or were deleted or merged. For example `currency.hpp` no longer exists, and the folder `eosiolib` is now deprecated. Any contracts written before v1.3 will require significant reworking.